# How to disable Navbar component in dynamic routes in next.js.?

Tags: url, next.js, next-router, dynamic-routing

I Know one way of doing this is by using the next router, but only in case when the route is static like `/dashboard'`.But how to do it when the URL is dynamic like `'/story/[slug]'`.

**Layout.js**

```
const Layout=({children })=>{
   if(router.pathname != '/dashboard')

return(
<>
{children()}
</>
)
else{
return(
<>
<Navbar/>
{children()}
</>
)
}
}
export default Layout;
```

This works but instead of `/dashboard` i need to implement this in all the dynamic routes under `/story` like `/story/[slug]` .

Thanks in advance

Comment: What about `router.pathname.includes('/story')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a simple javascript method: includes.

```
const App = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const withoutLayoutArray = [
    'story'
  ];

  const isWithoutLayout = withoutLayoutArray.includes(router.pathname);

  return isWithoutLayout ? (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Provider>
  ) : (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <NavBar>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </NavBar>
    </Provider>
  );
})
```